# Spring WS - return non-MTOM on MTOM request

Tags: spring, soap, jaxb, spring-ws

I have a SOAP service that receives a binary attachment (MTOM). The issue is that I would like to return a non-MTOM response (a "clean" SOAP return). The current code return a multipart response and uses "xop+xml" content-type.

The code is:

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebServiceConfig {

    @Value("${config1}")
    private String contextPath;

    @Value("${config2}")
    private String namespace;

    @Value("${config3}")
    private String wsdl;

    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean<?> webServicesRegistration(ApplicationContext ctx) {

        MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(ctx);
        messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);

        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(messageDispatcherServlet, contextPath, "*.wsdl");
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {

        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath(namespace);
        marshaller.setMtomEnabled(true);
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor methodProcessor(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        return new MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor(marshaller);
    }

    @Bean
    DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter endpointAdapter(MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor methodProcessor) {

        DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter adapter = new DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter();
        adapter.setMethodArgumentResolvers(Collections.singletonList(methodProcessor));
        adapter.setMethodReturnValueHandlers(Collections.singletonList(methodProcessor));
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleWsdl11Definition contentStore() {

        SimpleWsdl11Definition definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource(wsdl));
        return definition;
    }
}
```

I have tried changing to setMtomEnabled(false) - but then the request is not handled correctly.

Is the anyway of receiving MTOM - but returning a non-MTOM response?

Edit:

Endpoint looks like this:

```
@Endpoint
public class MyEndpoint {

    private ObjectFactory objectFactory;

    public MyEndpoint() {
        this.objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
    }
    
    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "SendMyRequest", namespace = "somenamespace")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<MyReceipt> store(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<MyRequest> storeContentRequest) throws IOException {
    
        MyReceipt receipt = new MyReceipt();
        receipt.setf1(123);
        receipt.setf2(456);
        return this.objectFactory.createMyResponse(receipt);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your endpoint.

Comment: @M.Deinum Added now.